# '".build\electron\Code - OSS.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, build, open-source, development-environment

I am trying to compile, run and debug VSCode according to the How to Contribute guideline. I would like to do this locally, not with a development container or within WSL2. I have completed these steps:

Installed Node v16.19.1
Installed yarn
Installed the ''Desktop Development with C++' workload for VS 2022
Forked and cloned the VS Code repo
ran yarn on it
Started the Build Task with Ctrl + Shift + B
I tried running ./scripts/code.bat directly. I get the following output and subsequent error:

```
PS F:\Programming\OSC\vsCode\vscode> .\scripts\code.bat
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node build/lib/electron
Done in 1.29s.
[12:18:56] Synchronizing built-in extensions...
[12:18:56] You can manage built-in extensions with the --builtin flag
[12:18:56] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug-companion@1.0.18 ✔︎
[12:18:56] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug@1.78.0 ✔︎
[12:18:56] [github] ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table@1.0.3 ✔︎
'".build\electron\Code - OSS.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried running ./scripts/code.bat directly.
I expect that the locally built vs-code application run
But it gives the specified error
'".build\electron\Code - OSS.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.